# Swap 2 object in a list with 2 props are String and Integer that an obj has MIN integer and one has MAX integer

Tags: java, swap

I have a List like this:
(A,6) (B,2) (C,9) (D,17) (E,8) (F,17) (G,2)
and the result look like this:
(A,6) (D,17) (C,9) (B,2) (E,8) (G,2) (F,17)

Here is my code:

```
Class car {
private String maker;
private int rate;
}

public void f2(List<Car> t) {
    int max = t.get(0).getRate();
    int min = max;
    for (Car car : t) {
        if(max < car.getRate())
            max = car.getRate();
        if(min > car.getRate())
            min = car.getRate();
    }
    System.out.println(min + "\t" + max);
    int indexMin = 0;
    int indexMax = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
        if(t.get(i).getRate() == min)
            indexMin = i;
        if(t.get(i).getRate() == max){
            indexMax = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(indexMin + "\t" + indexMax);
    Collections.swap(t, indexMin, indexMax);
    int a = 0; int b = 0;
    int count = indexMax;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if(t.get(i).getRate() == min)
            a = i;
        if(t.get(i).getRate() == max)
        {
            b = i;
            break;
        }
        
    }
    Collections.swap(t, a, b);
}
```

I want to improve my code to be better. Please help me!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *better* exactly. You mean code correctness, performance, readability?
Generally, StackOverflow is not a site for mentor-like questions.

Comment: You might have a better time getting answers at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but you still need a definition of "better".

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I just think my code is inefficient and want to improve it, but feel stuck in the process of improving and want someone's advice. Anyway, thank you very much